# Limits approaching infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I haven't done limits in a while so I just need a little refreshing. Could someone give a quite step by step run through please. Thanks

> For the function defined by $f(x)= \tfrac x {x − 4}$      determine ; $\lim\limits_{ x\to\infty}  f(x)$,
>                     $\lim\limits_{ x\to−\infty}  f(x)$ 
>                     $\lim\limits_{x→4^−} f(x).$
>       Hence write down the horizontal and vertical asymptotes of $f$.

Comment: We can't do that for you if you didn't show us some work you've done on the problem and where you're struggling.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

- The function can be rewrited as

$$\frac{x}{x-4}=1+\frac{4}{x-4}$$

- A vertical asymptote occurs where $x-4=0$, i.e. $x=4$.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac {x/x} {(x − 4)/x}=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac1{1-\frac4x}=\frac1{1-0}=\frac1{1}=1$. Similarly, 
$\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}\frac1{1-\frac4x}=\frac1{1-0}=\frac1{1}=1$. The horizontal line $y=1$ is an asymptote.

When $x\to 4^-$, the numerator approaches $4$, and the denominator approaches $0^-$, so the limit of $f$ is $-\infty$. The vertical line $x=4$ is an asymptote. When $x\to 4^+$, the numerator approaches $4$, and the denominator approaches $0^+$, so the limit of the fraction, $f$, is $\infty$.

See the graph at 
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+x%2F%28x-4%29+from+-5+to+10

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively:

When $x$ goes to infinity (plus or minus), there is no significant difference between $x$ and $x-4$ (indeed $-4$ becomes neglectible). So the ratio tends to $1$.

Now when $x$ approaches $4$, the numerator remains finite and positive ($x\approx4$) while the denominator tends to $0$ ($x-4\approx0$). The inverse of $0$ is $\pm\infty$, depending if you approach it by the right ($0^+$) or the left ($0^-$).

Now you know that for $x\to\pm\infty$, $y\to1$, and for $y\to\pm\infty$, $x\to4$.